# Why is Scala's Addable deprecated?

Tags: scala

I noticed that [`Addable`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.generic.Addable) is deprecated, while [`Subtractable`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.generic.Subtractable) is not. What's wrong with `Addable`, and why is `Subtractable` different?

Comment: This question and its answers makes me feel like I've wandered into a private Daniels club.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The problem is that `+` is overloaded to concatenate `String` to non-strings. So, whenever you use the `+` method on a type that doesn't have it, you'll get an error message that is not related to the real problem: that the type you have isn't the one you expected.

There's `+:` and `:+` to replace it.

Answer (score 20):

Expanding on Daniel's answer, `+` is also a very bad operator to use for collection insertion.  Mathematically, the `+` operator has a very conventional meaning, and part of that meaning is a guarantee of associativity.  Unfortunately, associativity is a guarantee that doesn't make any sense at all when you're adding an `Int` to a `Vector[Int]`.  As such, `+` was always a very confusing operator for anyone who had any algebraic training.

`+:` and `:+` are superior in several ways, not the least of which is that there is no expectation of associativity.  In fact, the very asymmetry of the operators imply *non*-associativity, which is precisely their semantics.  Also `+:` and `:+` mirror each-other very nicely, and `+:` is right-associative, all of which conspires to provide a very natural API for collection prepend and append, respectively.